# Setting Variables in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, variables, unix, scripting

I am a beginner at using Linux and trying to understand variables and scripting. I came across something that I do not understand and trying to figure out.

"The following command has been executed:

set 10 20 30 40 50

Enter the value of the variable $#:"

I understand that the variables $1=10 $2=20 and so on. So what would $# be?

Answer (score 1):

$# is a count of the variables you set.

```
for an example 


 line="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13"

   set -- `echo $line`

  echo $# 

 Here $# will print 13
```

But you can access only 9 variables from the count, you need to access remaining then you need to shift the elements using `shift`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ set 10 20 30 40 50
$ echo $#
5
```

Did you even bother to try the substance of your question?